# WhatsApp location pin won't retrieve the pin actual location (street, number, etc)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, geolocation, location-services

I have a ZTE nubia Z40S Pro which has an Android 12 under its own OS, MyOS 12.

Since the first day, I had this problem with the WhatsApp pin location. The real-time location works fine, but when I try to share a location and place a pin, it won't retrieve the actual location of the street, city, etc. When sent, the receiver gets a Google Maps pin for the whole city and country.

The same happens with Telegram, which makes me think there's some kind of permission that is not enabled that allows Whatsapp to retrieve the pin information. If I mark an existing interest point on the map, it will send the location, but not the red location pin.

Also, if I go to Google Maps, mark a location pin, and then go to Share and choose WhatsApp, the location pin will be attached correctly.

I've already allowed all the location permissions to both WhatsApp and Google Maps. I've also uninstalled completely both apps and reinstalled them again, but remain the same.

Does anyone have an idea of which permissions should be allowed, and if there's any way I can enable all the permissions for this app, or what's going on? Am I the first person who experience this?